# Loop over method in vue

Tags: vuejs2, django-rest-framework, axios

I want to be able to loop over all the invoices for a given client-year-month

I use django_filter in DRF to do some filtering on the backend, my endpoints look like this:

all invoices: http://127.0.0.1:8000/invoices/

filters: http://127.0.0.1:8000/invoices/?client=2&year=2020&month=5

I have a method that gets the results based on the filter, and a watch property for retrieving the data at the right time, in this case when a month is chosen.

```
methods: {
  retrieveResults() {
    this.$axios.$get('/invoices/', {
      params: {
        client: this.client,
        month: this.month,
        year: this.year,
      },
    });
  },
},

watch: {
  month: {
    handler: 'retrieveResults',
  },
},
```

The response I get looks like this (simplified):

```
[{
  "id":119,
  "client":2,
  "invoice_id":"2020001",
  "order_date":"2020-05-07",
},
{
 "id":120,
 "client":2,
 "invoice_id":"2020002",
 "order_date":"2020-05-07",
}]
```

Everything is working as expected, I see the right results in my network tab depending on the choices, my question is how do I v-for loop over this? I've tried numerous things, nothing has worked so far.

I tried wrapping the `retrieveResults` in a vuetify v-data-table, without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
// in a template:
<div v-for="invoice in invoices" :key="invoice.id">
// here is a component(s) for showing invoice content
</div>
...
// in a component:
data: {
   return {
     invoices: []
   }
},
methods: {
  async retrieveResults() {
   const { data: invoices} = await this.$axios.$get('/invoices/', {
      params: {
        client: this.client,
        month: this.month,
        year: this.year,
      },
    });
   this.invoices = invoices
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your insights, i have a slightly different result but your comment pointed me in the right direction.